# MapFragment is not getting initialised

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, mapfragment

I have been working in **Navigation Drawer Activity**, it has many fragments and one of the fragment contains **MapFragment**.

Now there is a problem in **MapFragment** i-e When for the first time i open the fragment that contains MapFragment inside it everything works fine, but once i navigate to some other fragment using `getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(...)`
and then return to previous fragment using `getFragmentManager().popBackStack();`

My `mapFragment.getView()` does not works, you can review my code for **MapFragment**

```
private void initMap() {


    if (mapFragment == null)
        mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapView);

    if (mapFragment == null)
        mapFragment = (MapFragment) this.getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapView);

    if (mapFragment == null) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "mapFragment not initialized", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    if (mapFragment.getView() == null) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "getView not initialized", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    mapFragment.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap mMap) {
            googleMap = mMap;
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "map intialized", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // For showing a "move to my location" button
            CheckPermissions cp = new CheckPermissions(getActivity());
            if (cp.getPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) || cp.getPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
                // enableMyLocation();
            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, LOCATION_PERMISSION);
            }
            mUiSettings = mMap.getUiSettings();
            mUiSettings.setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
            mUiSettings.setCompassEnabled(true);

            cameraListener();
            markerListener();
            mapListener();
        }
    });
}
```

above method is called if following method

```
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    initMap();


    if (mapFragment.getView() != null) {
        mapFragment.getView().setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

i have searched a lot on every platform but not getting any help.
and i do not want to use **SupportFragmentManager** because i'm not creating this app for older android versions.

Any help would be appreciable.
Regards.

**UPDATE**
I have sorted my problem temporarily by putting MapFragment inside RelativeLayout and hiding this RelativeLayout

```
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

initMap();

relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.rel_layout);
if (relativeLayout != null) {
    relativeLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I think your first line of code is what makes your fragment disappear.
Delete this:

```
if (mapFragment == null)
    mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapView);
```

Whenever you are adding a fragment as child to existing fragment, you want to use getChildFragmentManager().

EDIT:
To show / hide / remove child fragment, you can use one of the following methods:

```
getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().hide(fragment).commit();
```

getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction() has various methods for managing fragments, such as show / remove / replace / add, etc.

You can try these, though I'm not sure why you wish to hide MapFragment immediately after creating it.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but i have already tried it, sadly it does not helps :/

Comment: googlemap is getting initialized properly only problem is with mapFragment.getView() always returing null

Comment: MapFragment is, as the name suggests, a fragment. If you want to show / hide / remove it, use proper Fragment methods and FragmentManager instead of interacting with the view directly.

Comment: Also, mapFragment.getMapAsync() is an async method. It may be that the view is not yet initialized when you're calling the getView() method. Either way, it's better to use FragmentManager to change state of the fragment.

Comment: i just did not understand, can you show me some code for doing it with FragmentManager